# How to remove a subview if triggered from one of its components?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm looking for a smart way to remove a subview (with `removeFromSuperview`) when the subview itself (or precisely said one of its components) triggered the removal. As for the source code this would be like

```
UIView * sub_view = [[[UIView alloc] initWith...

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType...

[sub_view addSubview:button];

[self.view addSubview:sub_view];
```

If the button have now something like

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(closeMySubview) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

the call to `removeFromSuperview` inside `closeMySubview` does not work but results in SIGABRT and unrecognized selector sent to instance ... . Well that there is something not more present anymore is not a surprise but what would be the right way?

(Removing the subview if triggered from an another gui component would work of cause but is not the point here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best pattern for this type of action is the "delegate" pattern.

You can subclass anything and add this property:

```
@property (assign) id delegate;
```

for the instance variable:

```
id delegate;
```

Also, define a protocol like this:

```
@protocol MySubViewDelegate

    -(void)myViewDidFinish:(UIView *)view;
```

So in your view controller, you can instantiate the subview, tell it your its delegate, and add it to the view.  Then, an action on the subview calls the method:

```
[delegate myViewDidFinish:self];
```

The viewcontroller then can say something like:

```
[view removeFromSuperView];
```

Comment: This works. I assume the key is that the call leading to removeFromSuperview must be coming from the very same view which should be removed?!

Comment: Yes, this makes the most sense logically.  I like to think of it this way:
Suppose I show you a watch.  You look at it, and then decide you're finished.  Who's job is it to put the watch away, mine, or the watch's?

In this case, a view is showing you something.  Therefore, it should be up to that view how and when to put it away!

Answer (score 0):

It should work.

Check if your sub-view points to an existing view.

Post the entire code of the initiation and the `removeFromSuperview`.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like there's a coding error in closeMySubview.